# Entity Framework: How to get the EntitySetName of a TPT or TPH Entity

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have an Employee entity that inherits from a Person entity that inherits from a Resource entity (Employee -> Person -> Resource).  Is it possible to programmatically get the EntitySetName of Employee (which should be Resources)?

Comment: This could be worth a try: http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2009/12/03/entity-framework-programmatically-determining-the-entity-set-name-of-an-entity.aspx

Comment: @Slauma: That is an answer ;)

Comment: It works for everything but inherited entities.  The inherited entities don't show up in the BaseEntities list.  Good try though :)

Comment: @Ladislav: How could I have made sure that Google gets the possible reputation gain and not me when I had posted this as an answer :) But OK, you have forced ... ehm... encouraged (;)) me now to test this in detail, and there is actually a problem with derived types, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take the example from here...

http://msmvps.com/blogs/kevinmcneish/archive/2009/12/03/entity-framework-programmatically-determining-the-entity-set-name-of-an-entity.aspx

... and consider only the `else` case in the code snippet (so, we have no entity instance with a key):

```cs
// I have tested with EF 4.1/DbContext, for EF 4.0 forget this line
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

Type entityType = typeof(Employee);
string entityTypeName = entityType.Name;

var container = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(
    objectContext.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
string entitySetName = (from meta in container.BaseEntitySets
                        where meta.ElementType.Name == entityTypeName
                        select meta.Name).First();
string fullEntitySetName = container.Name + "." + entitySetName;
```

Now the problem is that this code throws an exception in `First()` because there is no `BaseEntitySet` with element type name equals "Employee". Obviously because there is only a set for the base type in the model = "Resource".

A possible fix is to change the second and third line above to:

```cs
Type entityType = typeof(Employee);
while (entityType.BaseType.Name != "Object")
    entityType = entityType.BaseType;
string entityTypeName = entityType.Name;
```

This should give back "Resources" as the `entitySetName` **IF**...

- Your entities are not derived from `EntityObject` (in this case it would probably work if you replace "Object" by "EntityObject" in the `while` loop above)
- Your entities are not derived from another custom type which is not an entity in the model. For example if you have `Resource` derived from a base type `MyBaseObject` but didn't include it in the model (there is no `DbSet<MyBaseObject>` or `ObjectSet<MyBaseObject>`) then you would have to replace "Object" by "MyBaseObject" in the `while` loop.

The second limitation is not nice because you could have different non-model base types in your entity classes which would make the code above not very general applicable.

Perhaps there is a smarter way to get the model base type directly from the `MetadataWorkspace`, but I don't know.

Comment: The while loop did it!  Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Also worked for me and I'm using EF1.  Had to use "EntityObject" instead of object.  Also, navigational properties in the specialized class can't be joined with linq queries.  You can still make the joins though if you start with the other object and then include the specialized class.  You have to navigate the relationship in the right direction (one way only).